# Outputting from random array into a text box

Tags: arrays, textbox

can anyone help with this ive tried allsorts.
Im trying to output from the array into the textbox

```html
<p>Code : <font color="green"><b>(Online)</b></font>: <input style="text-align:center;" id="code" readonly="readonly" size="25"  >
     </p>


<script>
var codes = [
 "634634",
 "636322",
 "884425",
 "272777" 
];

function RndText() {
        var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*codes.length);
        document.getElementById('code').innerHTML=codes[rannum];
}

window.onload = RndText;
</script>
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. You need to call `RndText` like `window.onload = RndText();` because you're calling a function. And secondly, you should set the `value` of an input, not the `innerHTML`.

Here is the updated code that will do what you're needing:

```js
var codes = [
  "634634",
  "636322",
  "884425",
  "272777"
];

function RndText() {
  var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * codes.length);
  document.getElementById('code').value = codes[rannum];
}

window.onload = RndText();
```

```html
<p>Code : <font color="green"><b>(Online)</b></font>:
  <input style="text-align:center;" id="code" readonly="readonly" size="25">
</p>
```